# Challenges with VBA when saving PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with a Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when I saving the PDF file. If I cancel save as, the VBA runs through correctly.

Er der nogen som kan hjælpe her?
Fejlen opstår når den skal gemme pdf på den lokation jeg har valgt.

```
Sub Gem_beregner_ny()

    Sheets("Udskrift").Visible = True
    Sheets("Udskrift").Select
     
      Dim strFileName As String
        Dim strPath As String

        strFileName = Range("F1").Value


        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = True Then
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
        Sheets("Udskrift").Select
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
         Sheets("Oplysningesskema").Select
         ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
         Range("D8").Select
            ActiveSheet.Protect "Salg-2022!"
             ActiveWorkbook.Protect "Salg-2022!"
   
                  
        Exit Sub
        End If

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
    "strPath & strFileName", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True

    End With

    Sheets("Udskrift").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Oplysningesskema").Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you change `"strPath & strFileName"` to `strPath & strFileName` without the quotes, does it behave any differently?

Answer (score 0):

Like [jsheeran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4742570/jsheeran) said, the filename goes without quotes, so your code should be

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
    strPath & strFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True
```

Comment: your answer is not clear - you write "the filename goes without quotes" - but in your code sample there are still the quotes :-/

Comment: Thanks, I've copy/paste it and forgot to remove it